# How to transfer ClockworkMod backup to PC?

Tags: file-transfer

I'm trying to transfer files on my Moto G x1032 (recognized by ADB) from `/data/media/0/clockworkmod/backup`(confirmed location) to my PC, but `adb pull` gives me `remote object /'location' does not exist`.

I can't copy the backup to storage with any file manager I've tried, and hence can't see the files on my computer.

[This seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307891/android-adb-pull-command-not-working-not-able-to-perform) but `/PB` doesn't help.

Comment: What's the full `adb` command you're entering? Perhaps it just needs a small adjustment.

Comment: `adb pull /sdcard/PB/data/media/0/clockworkmod/backup /C:\Users\ArtyNinja\Documents\Backup/1970-01-01.10.07.09_LXB22.46-28.1/`

Comment: The leading `/` in front of the local directory is not right. Your local path should be something like ``C:\Users\ArtyNinja\Documents\Backup\1970-01-01.10.07.09_LXB22.46-28.1\`` Windows doesn't use the `/` character in path separators.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
adb pull /sdcard/0/clockworkmod/backup C:\Users\ArtyNinja\Documents\Backup\1970-01-01.10.07.09_LXB22.46-28.1\
```

or

```
adb pull /sdcard/clockworkmod/backup C:\Users\ArtyNinja\Documents\Backup\1970-01-01.10.07.09_LXB22.46-28.1\
```

Comment: `Nope. The X1032 doesn't have external storage by the way.

Comment: External SD would be something like /external_SD.

Try your original command, but put a space after backup and C:, and make sure all of your /'s are pointing the same way, so try:

adb pull /sdcard/PB/data/media/0/clockworkmod/backup/ C:\Users\ArtyNinja\Documents\Backup\1970-01-01.10.07.09_LXB22.46-28.1\

Comment: Tried `adb pull /data/media/0/clockworkmod/backup /C: /Users/ArtyNinja/Documents/Backup/1970-01-01.10.07.09_LXB22.46-28.1/`, but still doesn't exist.

Comment: @RMarkwald `adb pull` expects two arguments, so your answer looks incomplete (rather like a comment) :) Furthermore, both arguments must be of the same type (i.e. either both a file, or both a directory). For me it always worked with the `/sdcard/*` path on the Android end.

Comment: @Izzy You are correct, I edited my original answer providing the full command.  /sdcard/* has always worked for me as well.

Comment: Thanks! I've done a bit formatting. But the first command looks wrong: shouldn't that start with `adb pull /storage/sdcard0` or `adb pull /data/media/0/`?

Comment: @ErljaJkdf. There's a space too much in your last comment, and a slash too much. Should read `adb pull /data/media/0/clockworkmod/backup C:/Users/ArtyNinja/Documents/Backup/1970-01-01.10.07.09_LXB22.46-28.1`. Could you please include the *full and exact* error message?

Comment: I've tried the edited command RMarkwald gave, and your command Izzy. The first returned `remote object '/sdcard/PB/data/media/0/clockworkmod/backup/' does not exist`, and your's returned `remote object '/data/media/0/clockworkmod/backup' does not exist`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention *“C:\”*, I'll assume you're on Windows OS. I know 2 possible solutions for your trouble:

.

#### 1) The easy and safe Ubuntu mode:

1. Download an Ubuntu ISO from **[HERE](http://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)**, burn the file on DVD/USB using the instructions you'll find at the bottom of above link and shutdown completely your computer. After a couple of seconds boot it using the LiveCD Mode where you don't need to install anything in order your Android device can be detected (and HDD's, Wifi, etc) after you connect it using your USB cable. Just ensure your computer is able to boot from DVD/USB device before your internal HDD (see your manual or BBS BIOS Post if a message such as *“Pres <kbd>F9</kbd> key to select boot device”* appears).
2. Copy the Backup folder from your Android device to your Internal HDD (or external USB drive if you want). Reboot after you've finished the process, remove the Ubuntu DVD/USB and Voilà; you're again on your Windows OS with your Backup folder safe on your HDD. Keep safe this DVD; maybe one day you could need it in order to recover your info stored on your HDD's if your computer wont work caused by any kind of viruses or other software problems.

Answer (score 0):

#### 2) The Pro and NO needing Computer Aroma mode:

1. Download AromaFM.zip from **[HERE](https://github.com/amarullz/AROMA-Filemanager/releases/download/1.91/aromafm-1.91.zip)** (despite the name, is a File Manager, not a Radio app). Put the apk into the root of your ExtSD card memory (if any).
2. Boot your device from CWM recovery (I use PhilzTouch, but I'm sure works also on CWM).
3. Navigate to “Install zip from SD card” and select the AromaFM Zip file.
4. After the AromaFM loads, you'll see a File Manager. Then copy your Backup folder to your external SD Card. If you previously connect a USB Pendrive or Card reader adapter to your USB port, then you can copy your info to any external media, since the AromaFM support the **OTG** method from the USB Debug.
5. After you finished the whole process, exit the app and turn off your device. Disconnect the Pendrive/Card reader adapter (if any) and turn ON your device. Now you have a Backup in another location than the original ones. Later you can to dump this data on a computer if desired.

.

#### Possible troubles using Aroma:

- You don't have a ExtSD card (or your device doesn't have a physical reader).
- Any of the Backup files have colon in the name (such as “Backup2015-10-10_12:00:00”).

The solution it's quite simple; use the Ubuntu method since GNU/Linux (Ubuntu) works perfectly managing files from Windows or another Linux distro (Android in fact is a Linux distro). Using the Ubuntu method you can not only copy the colon files on NTFS partition, but also can rename if its needed (you can't rename it from Windows. Even you can't move or open a file from Windows if in his name have a colon or exclamation; just an example).

- Your Filesystem is FAT32.
  If any of the backup files is higher than 4GB, then you're out of luck.

The only solution is format your SDcard/HDD partition (backup all important data before this, otherwise you'll lose all your stuff!) to NTFS format. Forget this message if you're using Vista or higher, since the Filesystem is NTFS. If you're on XP, then you could be using a deprecated Filesystem such as FAT32. If the trouble comes from your SDcard or external HDD, then format it to NTFS or make a partition and format it with NTFS filesystem. Again, you can do this using Gparted; a partition tool that comes by default on Ubuntu LiveCD you can download using the first method. Nevermind, sorry for sparing my comment, but  I can't send it in only one comment; the text editor said "It looks as spam". Anyway, hope that it help you!

Regards,

Benny.